# Empty response with urlilb2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've built a parser which use the below piece of code to download webpages. The code seems to work in a very random manner and returns sometimes empty responses.

I've tried to use time.sleep (3 sec) to see if it would resolve the issue but it still returns an empty answer from time to time.

I'm not sure why it is doing this and was wondering if anybody knew how to prevent this from happening ?

Thank you
Gilles

```
import urllib2

def process_requests():

    request = urllib2.Request('http://www.ssehl.co.uk/HALO/publicLogon.do')
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request) 


    print "response info", response.info()
    print "response code", response.getcode()
    print "response : ", response.read()[211:252]
    response.close()


for i in range(0,5):
    process_requests()
```

**Empty response example :**

response info Date: Mon, 25 Nov 2013 20:41:43 GMT
Server: Oracle-Application-Server-10g
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=a10c07c130d5fdeb7df75afa4d39b17ffa5d4101dacb.e38Pb34TaNqKbO0LbNaLax0Nbx0Oe0; path=/HALO
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

response code 200
**response :**

**correct response for the same request :**

response info Date: Mon, 25 Nov 2013 20:41:42 GMT
Server: Oracle-Application-Server-10g
Content-Location: http://www.ssehl.co.uk/HALO/jsp/notices/viewPublicNotices.jsp
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=a10c07c130d5b4139b6e961f496d89d5b49bb891e975.e38Pb34TaNqKbO0LbNaLax0Nbx0Oe0; path=/HALO
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

response code 200
**response : "meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0""**

Comment: for how long are you sleeping?

Comment: When you say empty answer, do you mean that `response.read()` returns `''`, or something else? If you get an error, post the traceback. And you're obviously printing things, so please post your *actual* output.

Comment: This might not be your fault. I can't get that page to load quickly or consistently.

Comment: I've posted the output of two calls in a row to the function. The first one returns a string with a length of 0 and the second returns the "meta ..." text. I've tried sleep  3 seconds and it still happens from time to time.

Comment: Running your code worked for me, but I left out the assignment statement for 'request'. It didn't seem to be necessary.